# How does locale() work regarding timezones?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I got a little bit confused about the [locale()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale). Does it only change the language display or will it also change timezone?

Can you give me some examples using the locale(), to show that it can change display or timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locale()` does not set the timezone, only the language

```
var fr = moment().locale('fr');
fr.locale().months(moment([2012, 0])) // "janvier"
fr.locale('en');
fr.locale().months(moment([2012, 0])) // "January"
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/adding-locale/

Comment: So no matter what happen, it still only change language right? Is there any code (situation) that could change the time by changing the locale()?

Comment: No, not with `locale()`. There's a whole separate moment library for changing timezones.http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Thank you, now I have no worry about the locate() could mess my clock.